# 2D Random walk program with squared distance

Tags: java

I need to create a program which simulates a random walker that takes n steps while printing the location at each step and finally the squared distance from the origin (x^2 + y^2) at the end. I feel like I'm doing something wrong because the squared distance at the end doesn't print the correct value, and I'm lost. Any help?

```
public class RandomWalker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int steps = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++){
        System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        double z = (int)(Math.random()*4); 
        if (z == 0) {
            x++;
        } else if (z == 1){
            y++;
        } else if (z == 2){
            x--;
        } else if (z == 3){ 
            y--;
        }

    }

    double sqd = (x*x) + (y*y);
    System.out.println("Squared distance = ");
    System.out.println(sqd);

    }
}
```

The expected output should look something like this:

```
(0,0)
(-1,0)
(-1,-1)
(-1,-2)
(-1,-3)
(-1,-4)
(-1,-5)
(0,-5)
(-1,-5)
(-2,-5)
(-2,-4)
Squared distance = 
20.0
```

The outputted squared distance is almost never right, however:

```
(0,0)
(0,-1)
(0,-2)
(0,-1)
(-1,-1)
(-2,-1)
(-3,-1)
(-3,0)
(-4,0)
(-4,1)
Squared distance = 
10.0
```

Comment: You give us no information here. What do you expect it to output, what did it actually output, and why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Updated my post. The major issue is the squared distance. It should be (x^2) + (y^2), but, for example, I know that (-4)^2 + (1)^2 isn't 10 so I don't know why I get that as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing one more iteration of your random walk after you print out the last pair of values, because the `println` statement is at the beginning of your loop. Put it at the end and the Squared distance will match the last co-ordinate pair that you output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    double z = (int)(Math.random()*4); 
    if (z == 0) {
        x++;
    } else if (z == 1){
        y++;
    } else if (z == 2){
        x--;
    } else if (z == 3){ 
        y--;
    }
    System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");        
}
```

You can solve these sorts of issues by stepping through your program with a debugger and inspecting the variable values.